# Airflow ExternalTaskSensor poking another dag all the time

Tags: python, airflow

I want to use ExternalTaskSensor。

```
TaskSensor = ExternalTaskSensor(
                            task_id='TaskSensor',
                            external_dag_id='datamart_OTT_CMS_v1',
                             external_task_id="end",
                             allowed_states=None,
                             execution_delta=None,
                             execution_date_fn=None,
                                dag=dag)
```

I write a dag B depend on A. When dag A end (successed) then dag B will run. But when it's running, I found that dag B is poking dag A all the time.
[image]

[image]

why? am I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

That's expected behavior. The `ExternalTaskSensor` is polling for DAG datamart_OTT_CMS_v1's "end" task to be complete. By default it checks every minute, but you can lower this interval by setting `poke_interval` (seconds) on the sensor.

Perhaps what you're looking for instead is the [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#airflow.operators.TriggerDagRunOperator). So instead of relying on polling, you can use this operator at the end of DAG A to trigger a run of DAG B.